# Struggling to debug AMPscript error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using the Add function to combine the rowcount of 2 DE's, and I'm struggling to understand what is wrong with my code.

```
%%[
var @rowCountset
@rowCount = DataExtensionRowCount("DE_1")
var @rowCount2 = DataExtensionRowCount("DE_2")
set @rowCountset Add(@rowCount, @rowCount2)
]%%

Output:%%=v(@rowCountset)=%%
```

Error: ***An expected comma is not found in the varible declaration. Script: var @rowCountset @rowCount = ListID: 889 Index: 20887***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
%%[
var @rowcount, @rowcount2, @rowcountset
set @rowCount = DataExtensionRowCount("DE_1")
set @rowCount2 = DataExtensionRowCount("DE_2")
set @rowCountset = Add(@rowCount, @rowCount2)
]%%

Output:%%=v(@rowCountset)=%%
```

You declare variables using `var` and `set` their values using set: https://ampscript.guide/setting-variables/

Comment: This looks good, have validated in amscript.io. However, it is now giving me the following error - An error occurred when attempting to parse TextEmailBody content for Text content. MemberID: 6278279 JobID: 0 ListID: 0 Content Begins With:

Comment: Please check the text version of your email